# How to validate form by changing colors of input when empty or not empty?

Tags: javascript

**Current Situation:** I have basic event listener set up when the form is being submitted.

**Event listener function:** Looks for empty fields and marks the input field red and places a placeholder saying `Required`.

```js
// Look for errors i.e. empty fields
document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("submit", (e) => {

    for(var i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll('#form input').length; i++) {
        // Check empty
        if(document.querySelectorAll('#form input')[i].value === "") {
            e.preventDefault();

            document.querySelectorAll('#form input')[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
            document.querySelectorAll('#form input')[i].placeholder = "Required";
            
        } else {
            document.querySelectorAll('#form input')[i].style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<form id="form">

<input>

<input>

<input>

<button>Submit</button>

</form>
```

**Goal:** If the current input is red, and user fills some data - I'd like it change the input back to white during user `input`. But not validating all inputs at once during user `input`, just the specific `input` targeted by user.

**Question:**

How can I have the current form validation on `submit` - then validate `selected` `input`?

Comment: You already know a) how to iterate over elements b) how to assign event listeners c) to use the `input` event. What are you waiting for? Just put all three together. This is the single most important skill in programming: transfer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this one :

```js
var firstTime = true;

document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#form input');
  
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    validate(inputs[i]);
  }
  if(firstTime){
    firstTime = false;
    inputs.forEach(function(item){
      item.addEventListener("input", (event) => {
        validate(item);
      });
    });
  }
});

function validate(item) {
  if (item.value === "") {
    item.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    item.placeholder = "Required";

  } else {
    item.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input>
  <input>
  <input>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi - are you able to explain why are you using `var firstTime = true`, and using it as `if` statement?

Comment: Also realized `e.preventDefault();` is in the wrong place :D ... I have used this `if ([...inputs].some(input => !input.value)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }`

Comment: Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

I added new event listener on input elements, so when you type into red inputs, they change back to white.

```js
// Look for errors i.e. empty fields
    document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("submit", (e) => {

        for(var i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll('#form input').length; i++) {
            // Check empty
            if(document.querySelectorAll('#form input')[i].value === "") {
                e.preventDefault();

                document.querySelectorAll('#form input')[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
                document.querySelectorAll('#form input')[i].placeholder = "Required";
                
            } else {
                document.querySelectorAll('#form input')[i].style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
            }
        }
    });

document.querySelectorAll('#form input').forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
    item.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  })
});
```

```html
<form id="form">
    <input>
    <input>
    <input>
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check all the input and assign a event listener to each input to listen change event.

```js
// Look for errors i.e. empty fields
document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#form input')
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].value === '') {
      inputs[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
      inputs[i].placeholder = "Required";
    }
    inputs[i].addEventListener("change", (e) => {
      if (e.target.value) {
        e.target.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
      }
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<form id="form">

  <input>

  <input>

  <input>

  <button>Submit</button>

</form>
```

Comment: When I type data - then go off it - then go back on it, remove the data - go another field - its still white

Comment: red color is coming when you are submitting but white color is coming when you are changing the data. If there is a data in input then it will set white we are not setting red again. If you want to set then do change in input listener.